# Fastlane and Gitlab CI with Xcode-Workspace

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, fastlane

I had the following file structure of a Xcode project:

```
projectname.xcworkspace
iOS/
macOS/
tvOS/
```

In the folders iOS, macOS and tvOS are the projects for the app of this operating system. The common source code for all three operating systems are in swift packages.

If I initialize Fastlane in to folder with xcworkspace, the fastlane script not working and the error „Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode“ occur in GitLab CI. If I initialize Fastlane in the subfolders the fastlane script working perfekt in the GitLab CI.

If I started the fastlane script in the root folder in a terminal with the command `bundle exec fastlane lanename`, it works perfectly.

What can I do that the fastlane script works under GitLab CI in the root folder ?